# How to add total number of combinations in my code? C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

Here I have the code that solves the following riddle.
A farmer goes to a market with 100 bucks. He wants to spend exactly 100 bucks and exactly 100 animals to buy. Sheep cost 8 bucks, chickens cost 3 bucks, rabbits cost only 0.50 bucks each.
In the code I have some of the vaild combinations printed out. The problem is now how do I make it show the total number of combinations that have been checked.

```
using System;


    namespace riddle
    {
    class Program
    {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int priceSheep = 8;
        int priceChicken = 3;
        float priceRabbit = 0.5F;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100 / priceSheep; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= ((100 - i * priceSheep) / priceChicken); ++j)
            {
                int money = (100 - priceSheep * i - priceChicken * j);
                if (priceRabbit * (100 - i - j) == money)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " " + "sheeps" + " " + j + " " + "chickens" + " " + (100 - i - j) + " " + "rabbits");
                }
            }
        }

      }
   }
 }
```

Current output:

```
0 sheeps 20 chickens 80 rabbits
1 sheeps 17 chickens 82 rabbits
2 sheeps 14 chickens 84 rabbits
3 sheeps 11 chickens 86 rabbits
4 sheeps 8 chickens 88 rabbits
5 sheeps 5 chickens 90 rabbits
6 sheeps 2 chickens 92 rabbits
```

What the final output should look like:

```
0 sheeps 20 chickens 80 rabbits
1 sheeps 17 chickens 82 rabbits
2 sheeps 14 chickens 84 rabbits
3 sheeps 11 chickens 86 rabbits
4 sheeps 8 chickens 88 rabbits
5 sheeps 5 chickens 90 rabbits
6 sheeps 2 chickens 92 rabbits
1030301 combinations checked
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken. Just add another variable and increment it inside your inner loop.

Comment: please dont forget to select an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just tally up the count and display it at the end.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int priceSheep = 8;
        const int priceChicken = 3;
        const float priceRabbit = 0.5F;
        int combinationsChecked = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100 / priceSheep; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= ((100 - i * priceSheep) / priceChicken); ++j)
            {
                int money = (100 - priceSheep * i - priceChicken * j);
                if (priceRabbit * (100 - i - j) == money)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " " + "sheeps" + " " + j + " " + "chickens" + " " + (100 - i - j) + " " + "rabbits");
                }

                combinationsChecked++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{combinationsChecked} combinations checked");

    }
}
```

That being said, you can solve this problem without brute-forcing in much much shorter time. All you care about is the average cost of an animal (1$), so just combine animals intelligently until their average cost is 1$. Then multiply that combination until you've got 100 animals. Of course, your total number of animals in the combination will need to be a factor of 100. I bet you can make a 5 animal combination that works

Update: here is how I solved your problem in only 146 combinations checked. It works for any number of animals with any prices:

```
internal class AnimalCosts
{
    public static Dictionary<string, int> GetOptimalAnimalCounts(decimal totalDollars, int totalAnimals,
        List<(string name, decimal cost)> animals, out int combinationsChecked)
    {
        combinationsChecked = 0;
        var averageCost = totalDollars/totalAnimals;
        var factors = Factor(totalAnimals);
        factors.Sort();
        var costs = animals.Select(a => a.cost).ToList();
        foreach (var animalsInCombination in factors)
        {
            var combination = new int[animalsInCombination];
            if (FindCombination(combination, 0, costs, averageCost * animalsInCombination, out var optimalCombination,ref combinationsChecked))
            {
                var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                var multiplier = totalAnimals / animalsInCombination;
                foreach (var index in optimalCombination)
                {
                    var animalName = animals[index].name;
                    if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(animalName, out var count))
                    {
                        count = 0;
                    }

                    count += multiplier;
                    dictionary[animalName] = count;
                }

                return dictionary;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    static bool FindCombination(int[] currentCombination, int index, List<decimal> costs, decimal targetSum, out int[] combination, ref int combinationsChecked)
    {
        combinationsChecked++;
        if (index >= currentCombination.Length)
        {
            var sum = currentCombination.Select(item => costs[item]).Sum();
            combination = currentCombination;
            return sum == targetSum;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < costs.Count; i++)
            {
                currentCombination[index] = i;
                if (FindCombination(currentCombination, index + 1, costs, targetSum,
                        out combination, ref combinationsChecked)) return true;
            }

            combination = currentCombination;
            return false;

        }
    }
    


    static List<int> Factor(int number)
    {
        var factors = new List<int>();
        int max = (int)Math.Sqrt(number);  // Round down

        for (int factor = 1; factor <= max; ++factor) // Test from 1 to the square root, or the int below it, inclusive.
        {
            if (number % factor == 0)
            {
                factors.Add(factor);
                if (factor != number / factor) // Don't add the square root twice!  Thanks Jon
                    factors.Add(number / factor);
            }
        }
        return factors;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The number of combinations should be the number of times the `if` statement was checked, which is to say, the number of times the outer loop executed times the number of times the inner loop executed.

Add a counter `int combinationsChecked = 0;` outside of the outerloop and after the `if` statement in the inner loop increment this counter by one. Then, after the outer loop finishes executing print the result.

```
int combinationsChecked = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 100 / priceSheep; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= ((100 - i * priceSheep) / priceChicken); ++j)
    {
        int money = (100 - priceSheep * i - priceChicken * j);
        if (priceRabbit * (100 - i - j) == money)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + " " + "sheeps" + " " + j + " " + "chickens" + " " + (100 - i - j) + " " + "rabbits");
        }
        combinationsChecked++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine($"{combinationsChecked} combinations checked");
```